How to set Azure Synapse Pipeline Dataflow Rest Source Relative URL dynamic variable?
How do I set this locationid value dynamically in the relative URL of my DF Rest Source:

My design pattern is: 
I need to pass the locationid from a query lookup to the ForEach. This should loop through 10 location ids.
I pass to the ForEach:

I Set the variable:

I create the parameter in the REST connection:

I set the parameter in the Relative URL:

When I debug, I'm getting all these DF errors that look like it isn't making the first connection still.

What am I doing wrong?
Currently getting this error:

Thanks. John

are you getting the above error in the pipeline run when the dataflow activity is in deactivated state?

I have deactivated the DF and am trying to ensure the Lookup --> to --> ForEach is working correctly, but I am getting errors there.
My lookup is returning:
"firstRow": {
"locationid": 4520328863809536
},
The ForEach is erroring with:
'length(activity('Lookup1').output.value)' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist,

ahh, I had FirstRow checked on the Lookup. That was throwing off the JSON results. I now have the Lookup, ForEach and SetVariable working correctly, looping through the 10 results:
{
"name": "locationid",
"value": 4626555107147776
}
The Dataflows are still failing though. Not sure what I am doing wrong there.

got the ADF working and dynamically setting the filename now. This was a helpful resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Is1tQIxxVyU

When dealing with flattening of the multiple files dynamically in the dataflow, you need to make sure your all input files have same schema. If the schema is different, then it won't work in the dataflow.
After creating the dataflow with REST source dataset parameters, first you need to create flatten transformation. As this needs the schema, first import your any API schema by giving static values to your source dataset parameters.

Click on save and the input schema will be imported. Now, do the flatten transformation on this schema and check its working in the dataflow debug data preview like below sample.

When you run the data preview, this will take the data from the given static value API.
Give your sink file settings.

Give the values to the dataset parameters and the dataflow parameter from the pipeline. In this demo, I have passed the pipeline expression @concat('myrest_res_file',string(item()),'.json') as value to the dataflow parameter.

Even though it took the data from the given static values API in the dataflow debug, when you hit the pipeline run, it will take the values from the pipeline for-each. In each iteration, it will take these values and flattens this data as per the already given schema. As the schema is same, it will generate the expected results.
Sample Result:

